# Geckodriver For Kali Linux

Tags: selenium, firefox, geckodriver

uname -m gives
arm7l 
as my platform

I need to run selenium in My Firefox-esr browser.

Which is the geckodriver binary suitable for my platform?

Comment: it should work on the Linux 32 or 64 https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: arm7l is 32 bit.I tried both linux 32 and linux 64 versions.But it is not working.